# Find largest ellipse in basin of attraction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the following system:
$$
\begin{align}
x' &= -x+y^2 \\
y' &= -2y + 3x^2 \\
\end{align}
$$
I am asked to find the largest ellipse of the form: $$ V(x,y) = \tfrac{x^2}{2} + \tfrac{y^2}{4} = r$$
contained in the region of attraction of the system.

We can use $V(x,y)$ as a Lyapunov function of the system and we get:
$$V'(x,y) = xx' + \tfrac{y}{2}y' = -x^2 +xy^2 -y^2 + \tfrac{3}{2} x^2y$$

I deduced we are looking for $r$ such that:
\begin{align}
r &= \min_{(x,y) \neq (0,0)} \tfrac{x^2}{2} + \tfrac{y^2}{4}\\
&\text{ s.t } -x^2 +xy^2 -y^2 + \tfrac{3}{2} x^2y=0 
\end{align}
I have not been able to solve this problem analytically using the Lagrangian (a 3rd-degree polynomial comes up). Wolfram Alpha solution seems to be right ($r \simeq 0.4782$) when plotted though:

[image]

Is this way of reasoning sound? Is there some simplification that allows us to get an analytical solution?
Thanks in advance

EDIT: I have found the answer in the book, apparently the correct result is $\frac{1}{9}$. So there must be an error in my reasoning I cannot find. The book offers no solution, so I still don't know how to correctly solve the exercise.

Comment: @Moo Thank you for your interest. I looked at both examples before posting but the answers mainly rely on non-analytical methods. The only answer with an analytical method implies solving the equation, which I don't think is expected here.

I know how to find the solution using Wolfram Alpha, I am interested in getting an analytical solution if that is possible.

Comment: Clearly $1/9$ is way too small. What is “the book” that you are referring to?

Comment: @HansLundmark The book is Hale and Kocak: Dynamics and bifurcations. It is exercise 9.19.

Comment: You're correct that if $r_0$ is the smallest real root of $1377 r^5 - 23056 r^4 + 72395 r^3 - 29378 r^2 - 56 r - 1$, then any trajectory with $V(x_0, y_0) \leq r_0$ converges to the origin. But $r$ can be increased, as long as the ellipse doesn't touch the separatrices comprising the stable manifold of the equilibrium point $((2/3)^{2/3}, (2/3)^{1/3})$. The reason the supremum is greater than $r_0$ is that a trajectory can intersect the curve $\dot V = 0$.

Comment: It's clearly a mistake in the book. Your value of $r$ seems to be fine when plotting the ellipse on top of the phase portrait too. (Your ellipse is just a little smaller than the ellipse going through the saddle point at $(x,y)=(a^2,a)$, where $a=(2/3)^{1/3}$, and it looks like it might be tangential to the trajectory approaching that saddle point from the lower right, but it's hard to say for sure just from the plot. Maybe not.)

Comment: An more interesting question is perhaps if it's possible to “save” the problem, i.e., if there's some simple modification of it that actually has $1/9$ as the correct answer (and hence is what the authors actually intended).

Comment: @HansLundmark Maybe I'm wrong but if we increase $r$ then there would be a point in the ellipse in V' >0 (since for the value I found for $r$ the ellipse is tangent to $\dot{V}=0$) but the points on that region diverge.

Comment: @Zanzag: Even if you start at a point where $V'>0$, you may enter the basin of attraction of the origin after a while (at least in general, but in the phase portrait it looks like it can actually happen in this case). So that conclusion is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to solve

$$
\min_r \ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \cases{-x^2 + x y^2 - y^2 + 3/2 x^2 y = 0\\ \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{4}=r}
$$

is by way of tangency.  After substitution of $x$ and posterior squaring we have

$$
\frac{144 r^2 y^2}{17}-\frac{192 r^2 y}{17}+\frac{64 r^2}{17}-\frac{104 r y^4}{17}+\frac{32 r y^2}{17}+y^6+\frac{12 y^5}{17}+\frac{4 y^4}{17}=0
$$

This polynomial should have at least a double root (tangengy) so

$$
\frac{144 r^2 y^2}{17}-\frac{192 r^2 y}{17}+\frac{64 r^2}{17}-\frac{104 r y^4}{17}+\frac{32 r y^2}{17}+y^6+\frac{12 y^5}{17}+\frac{4 y^4}{17}=(y-y_1)^2(y^4+a y^3+b y^2+c y +d)
$$

and the coefficients which guarantee nullity are

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 d y_1^2-\frac{64 r^2}{17} = 0\\
 c y_1^2-2 d y_1+\frac{192 r^2}{17} = 0\\
 b y_1^2-2 c y_1+d-\frac{144 r^2}{17}-\frac{32 r}{17} = 0\\
 a y_1^2-2 b y_1+c = 0\\
y_1^2 -2 a y_1+b+\frac{104 r}{17}-\frac{4}{17} = 0\\
 a-2 y_1-\frac{12}{17}=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

which gives the possible real solutions

$$
r = \cases{
0\\
0.4782377831432382\\
3.5153505723608345\\
12.75203735221895
}
$$